# Why can't gdb find the symbol table?

Tags: debugging, gdb, core-file

everyone.

I'm trying to fix a problem in ceph using its core file and gdb.
According to the following output, gdb should had successfully loaded debug symbols from ceph-debuginfo:

```
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/ceph-osd...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/ceph-osd.debug...done.
```

However, it still couldn't find the symbol table when I used "bt" to trace the stack:

```
#0  0x000000393da0f65b in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x0000000000a51636 in install_standard_sighandlers () at global/signal_handler.cc:121
No locals.
#2  0x00007fc7a77f9ed0 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007fc7a77f9e10 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007fc7a77f9b90 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007fc66d3142e0 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007fc7fac64100 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x0000003900000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x0000000000a51155 in SignalHandler::unregister_handler (this=0x1105440, signum=<value optimized out>, handler=<value optimized out>) at global/signal_handler.cc:317
No locals.
#9  0x000000393eabcc33 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#10 0x000000393eabcd2e in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
```

Why is this happening?

PS: when gdb started running, it prompted the following warning:

```
BFD: Warning: /home/xuxuehan/online_problems.2016-11-19.7-01/core-ceph-osd-6-32337-32337-19906-1479510049 is truncated: expected core file size >= 8372899840, found: 7439335424
```

Could this be the cause of gdb not finding the symbol table?

Comment: Are you compiling with `-g` or similar ?

Comment: No, I didn't compile the executable with -g, but I built its debug info, and this debug info is loaded when gdb starts running as is presented in the question.

Comment: so how do you exactly build this debug info?

Comment: There is no other way I know than building sources with -g, -ggdb etc.

Comment: I built it with -g

Answer (score 1):

This could be the symbols from shared libraries.

Launch:

```
 ldd your_binary
```

and see what shared objects it is using.
Then download debug symbols for this so's.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply:-) It seems that all the "so"s are third party libraries. However, most of the methods being invoked should be ceph's own methods which are all within the "ceph-osd" binary body. Is there any other possible causes? I found that the few methods whose symbols are found are all "C" methods, while ceph is mostly written in C++, is there any difference between loading symbols of C code and that of C++ code? Could that be a cause?

Comment: As far as I know this could be also caused by libstdc++ version mismatch between compilation and your environment.

Comment: Is there any way to detect which version of libstdc++ I used to compile the ceph-osd that created the core file? Since the executable that created the core file was built a long time ago, I couldn't remenber which version of libstdc++ is built with it

Comment: if you are using the same environment for building and running it's not the point here

Comment: I built it a long time ago, and I can't remember if it was built with the same version that I'm building with now.

Comment: still all libraries are rather backward compatible. You can check the output of `strings <your_binary> | grep GLIBC` and compare with the output from the same command for libstdc++

Comment: check also what debug symbols do you have in your binary by `nm --debug-syms <binary>`

Comment: Hi, I've checked that I did compile the source with -g, and the versions of libstdc++ are the same. And even there is no the "core file truncated" warning, gdb still can't find the symbol table, why?

Comment: have you checked the output on `nm`? Check if there are symbols that gdb couldn't find. Maybe not all of your files was compiled with -g. Maybe you set only CFLAGS but not CXXFLAGS.

Comment: I checked the g++ commands in the output of make, all of them are with -g.

Comment: Well, I need to correct something. Previously, I said that the few methods whose symbols are found are all "C" methods. This is not true, some of them are C++ methods